# Use of Key Up event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, selenium-webdriver

I want to validate my `textbox` using `jquery`.

If the number of letters' length increased to 6, it will hide my `<span>` tag

html:

```
<input type="password" id="txtpass" value="" onkeyup="KeyUp();"/>
```

javascript:

```
function KeyUp () {        
    var x =$("#txtpass").val();
    if (x.length < 6) {
        $("span").show()
    }
    else 
        (x.length >= 6)
    {
        $("span").hide();
    }
}
```

Advise please

Comment: The `(x.length >= 6)` part seems to be redundant. Just remove it and leave `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keyup function of jquery and look for length and show/hide *(or use toggle)*:

```
$('#txtpass').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length < 6){
        $("span").show();
    }
    else if($(this).val().length >= 6){
       $("span").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the password's length by `keyup` or `input` event:

```js
    $('#txtpass2').on('blur', function() {
      var shouldShowAlert = ($(this).val().length < 6);
      $("#passAlert2").toggle(shouldShowAlert);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
use oninput<input type="password" id="txtpass" value="" oninput="validatePass(this)"/>
<span id='passAlert'>Length is too short</span>
<script>
  function validatePass(target) {
    var shouldShowAlert = (target.value.length < 6);
    $("#passAlert").toggle(shouldShowAlert);
  }
</script>
<br/>
use onblur<input type="password" id="txtpass2" value=""/>
<span id='passAlert2' style="display: none;">Length is too short</span>
```

Below is jquery way:

```
$('#txtpass').on('input', function() {
  var shouldShowAlert = ($(this).val().length < 6);
  $("#passAlert").toggle(shouldShowAlert);
});
```

Comment: can it be used with blur() function?

Comment: Yes, then it'll validity when you lose focus to this input, change `oninput` to `onblur` in first, and change `.on('input', ...)` to `.on('blur', ...)` in jquery way.